# php cUrl to command line curl call

Tags: php, curl

There at **many** threads on converting command line curl commands to php cURL resources.  I need to do the *opposite*.  I'm trying to debug some critical vendor code and would like to do a diff.  Is this possible?  In chrome, when a network request fires, you can copy the network request as a curl command (single string!).  I am hoping the php curl lib may offer something similar?

Comment: There's no automatism for that. Just look at the [manpage](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) and translate the options yourself. Or is this about a specific parameter?

Comment: i didn't build the **large** curl code segments involved in this problem.  instead of reverse engineering the curl resource construction, I was hoping to just do a diff on their command output to determine the changed parameter.  sounds like that may not be feasible.  I'll go ahead and dig in then. Thx!

Comment: I'm not sure it will provide exactly what you're looking for, but enabling CURLOPT_VERBOSE may provide some helpful insight.  If you don't have access to STD_ERR output (i.e. you're not running on command line), you can redirect output to a file using CURLOPT_STDERR.

Comment: Would it be of any value to try POSTMAN from Chrome Tools? I have found it to be a good way to test input params vs expected output.

Comment: An possibility could also be the use of an network sniffer (e.g. wireshark) to analyze directly the HTTP communication done by curl.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert Php CURL request to command line curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42671535/how-to-convert-php-curl-request-to-command-line-curl)

Answer (score -5, accepted):

**Please note that the following answer is just a work-around, there's no such library for PHP (yet)!**

---

You can convert cURL commands to PHP code with *incarnate*'s **[cURL-to-PHP](https://github.com/incarnate/curl-to-php)** tool.
It is available online at: https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/

The converter logic is written in JavaScript, you can check its source code on the project's git repository: https://github.com/incarnate/curl-to-php

Comment: This does exactly the opposite what OP is requesting

Comment: Exactly. If you want to implement the reverse logic, you can use the library I linked as an aid. It has all the cURL parameters and options so you don't need to research everything from ground up. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Chrome "Developer Tool" (Open with F11). Then you will see "network" tab.
Open this before you visit wanted url.
Inside this tab you will see all request to this domain. Click on the first request and on the right you will see
another tabs "headers", "preview", "response", "cookies", "timing".
In "headers" tab are headers sent in http for this page. This headers you can use in curl.

EDITED -> If communication is without UI, You need some proxy software like:
http://proxyworkbench.com/

Comment: thanks for the input. however, this wasn't an option.  i had an apache server making a call to another apache server.  no UI involved!

Comment: you can see my modified post how to do that.

Answer (score -1):

Steps

1. install fiddler and enable it to listen to port 8888(by default)
2. Change php server side curl domain code and make sure the new domain is pointing to localhost:8888. This way all traffic is routed through fiddler
3. Capture the request and take a session copy
4. compare the versions

Comment: A word of warning on this answer - I'm not familiar with the fiddler software but I went ahead and installed it - now my internet connection only works while I have this software running - I am now figuring out how to fix that up -- but for others : DO NOT USE THIS ANSWER UNLESS YOU KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING AND UNDERSTAND THE IMPLICATIONS

Comment: fiddler is just a proxy sitting between your browser and internet. You should uninstall if you dont understand to use fiddler